# Is it a good security practice to force employees hide their employer to avoid being targeted?

Tags: phishing, corporate-policy

A young tech company which operates on sensitive data has employees that fall victim to phishing/porting scams despite its best efforts to instill security fobs, vpn, password managers, non-sms 2FA, limited email access and so on.

Is it a good practice to force employees to hide their employment status from the public to avoid being targeted for hacking (e.g. remove the employer from LinkedIn)?

Comment: "Is it good practice?" or "Is it effective?" Who are the threat actors?

Comment: Is it effective is probably the better question. Unsure who the threat actors are other than those wishing to gain access to sensitive data through employee vulnerabilities.

Comment: You might want to check with local laws first.  Forcing employees to not reveal who they work for on linked in may be seen as an anti-competitive, and anti-labor and may not even be legal.  I'd tell the company to stuff it if they said I can't post who I work for on a website.

Comment: *"security fobs, vpn, password managers, non-sms 2FA, limited email access and so on."* The problem seems obvious to me: you're describing technical solutions but you're worried about a *human* vulnerability. Are you doing anything to train the staff on how to respond to social engineering or phishing? All the password managers and policies in the world will fail to help if you're not also emphasizing the behavioral element. The tech- and policy-heavy approach can lull people into a false sense of security, if anything.

Comment: It really depends on the company's threat model, where did you say you worked again?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_Personnel_Management_data_breach even the US Gov't can't manage to keep secret the people who have top secret clearance, keeping it secret who works for you may not be a particularly strong mitigation.  Are the e-mail addresses not going to gradually show up in mined data anyway?

Comment: What are *"porting scams"*? Are you talking about mobile phone SIM swapping and fraud?

Comment: What makes you think you have that power anyway?

Comment: @SteveSether I think it's probably legal in the U.S. I know I've been told not to put my employer on social media and not to wear my security badge while off-site when I was working at a DoD base in the past. This instruction was given by base security. I'd imagine DoD's horde of lawyers, including the on-base JAG office, was well aware of the practice.

Comment: @reirab I have no problem that DoD, or CIA, NSA, etc has the right to tell you you can't say who you work for.  Words like "National Security" tend to make courts allow just about anything, and many laws designed to protect employees often don't apply to the government (polygraph for instance).  Private corporations, however, are another matter entirely.  Not long ago major tech companies were caught agreeing to a "no poaching" agreement where they wouldn't try to recruit each others employees.  IIRC they were fined for this practice.

Comment: @SteveSether You're right, but there are also a lot of private companies doing national security work for the government. I was working for a private contractor when I worked there, too. I wasn't sure exactly how 'sensitive' OP's company's data was. I suspect the exact level of sensitivity would impact the legality of OP's proposal and it would certainly affect whether it was a reasonable precaution or not. As with any security matter, it's important to understand the threat model when deciding what security measures are reasonable responses to that threat.

Comment: @dwizum Obligatory XKCD reference https://xkcd.com/538/, the reason that Phishing is done is because it works.

Comment: @reirab isn't that guidance mostly to prevent employees being hassled by any stranger who sees the pass and reacts as opposed to being an actual security thing?

Comment: @Aron yeah, that was kind of my point. And, phishing is a social phenomenon, you can't solve it with purely technical solutions. You need to address the human, with training and cultural/behavioral change.

Comment: @Baldrickk At least at the base where I worked, it was presented as more of a security issue. Harassment by locals wasn't too much of a concern, but our base had a lot of Secret and Top Secret R&D, so employees being forced to act under duress was a pretty significant concern (though perhaps not as much now as back in the Cold War era.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hiding your *employer* would not appear to be of any use at all when you want to hide the employee's *email address* from the public. If you hide your employer info but spread your contact details far and wide, the employer info is not interesting.

The assumption being made is that once you know the company name and the employee name, then one can freely email the employee. Trying to address the threat of incoming emails by trying to hide the company name, so that the email address domain can't be guessed, so that emails cannot be addressed **is trying to push on the wrong end of the lever of control**. And you are trying to do it with a wildly difficult policy to enforce.

The trivially effective control is to break the direct tie between company name, employee name, and email address.

I know of companies that stand up a separate domain to send emails from. So `example.com` stands up `example-email.com`. This immediately wipes out a lot of automated emails. Other companies salt the email address with 2-4 numbers, so `kelly.smith@example.com` becomes `kelly.smith.1234@example.com`. Others use only the employeeID number: `12345678@example.com`.

While each one of these can be overcome through analysis of other disclosed email addresses from the company, it is more effective and much, much easier to control and enforce through technical means than forcing people not to disclose where they work.

The company name is simply not the primary data to control in this threat scenario. *It's the email addresses*. You can control those.

Managing digital footprint is always a good *consideration* but you have an awareness problem and a trust problem with your employees that such a policy is not going to address.

Comment: Does not fully make sense to me. If one knows from Linkedin that Mr. John Doe works for acme (acme.com), would they try to contact/phish `john.doe@acme.com` *first*?

Comment: Perhaps, but then they would have to figure out the naming convention, etc. The primary thing to protect, in the proposed threat scenario, is the contact details. If that's the concern, then you can do things like not use the person's name in the email, etc.

Comment: It's not just a matter of wanting to hide the employee's e-mail address. It's a matter of not wanting to advertise who works there, so that they're less likely to be targeted for spear phishing (or, depending on the attacker and their objectives, even hostage-taking) in the first place. If an attacker doesn't know the employee is an employee in the first place, they won't care what their e-mail address is or be looking for it. Of course, this is assuming that they're not advertising their employer by using an employer-provided e-mail account for personal reasons.

Comment: @schroeder there's less than a dozen common naming convention. It's not a terribly difficult thing to brute-force and easily automated.

Comment: @reirab but that's incredibly difficult to control or prevent. Protecting the email address is the trivial control.

Comment: @tom then don't make addresses like that. I'm really confused about the debate around this.

Comment: @schroeder - almost everybody uses email addresses like this. It's not going to change. Businesses need it to be like this. So the debate is not "change email addresses" it's how do we help secure email when this is what we have.

Comment: @schroeder that is insanity. There's a reason e-mails are made like this that trumps a bit of spam and phishing: If a potential client or partner met John Doe somewhere but forgot to take his business card, he should be able to reach him at some easily predictable address.

Answer (score 22):

The best security practice is to train the employees specifically to avoid phishing and scams in general. Also, you need to test them periodically, to check if they are actually reacting to scams as they were trained to do. Password managers with auto-complete functionality might also help because they can be used to detect wrong URLs before entering sensitive data on the internet. Hiding employment status seems useless to me, because its usefulness is going to be negligible compared to the best practice I mentioned above (training and testing).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94897/discussion-on-answer-by-reed-is-it-a-good-security-practice-to-force-employees-h).

Answer (score 11):

[Schroeder's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/211696/163495) explains things very well, but I would like to offer a different view.

Employees will likely act online. They will ask questions on Stack Exchange, in support forums of vendors, etc.

If it's apparent whom they work for (e.g. by using the email address `j.doe@awesomecorp.com`), then an attacker looking to gain information about Awesome Corp will be able to gather information about systems being used by the company. Depending on how much information they (knowingly or unknowingly) expose, this may include:

- Configuration data
- Products and versions thereof used by the company
- Credentials
- Internal addresses
- Etc.

While this in itself may not directly constitute a vulnerability, it can show an attacker potential entry points and allows them to more efficiently understand the architecture of Awesome Corp.

The idea that J. Doe should hide that he is working for Awesome Corp is not necessarily useful. The problem arises when J. Doe discloses internal information.

As such, employing an information disclosure policy is very useful for the company. It should contain which information can be shared with vendors, the public, etc. In addition, employees should have someone to talk to if they are uncertain whether or not something is considered internal information.

Comment: That's all good too, but not about phishing or social engineering, as the OP is focused.

Comment: @schroeder And it's mentioned that it shouldn't be a concern, in general. You can observe this on every conference, when people start with "Hi, my name is ... and I work for ...".

Comment: So it would appear that you haven't answered the question but raised a secondary topic.

Comment: I disagree, in the sense that these two are closely related. "Hiding your employer for the sake of not being targeted for phishing" and "Hiding your employer for the sake of preventing information gathering" are, in my opinion, related enough and provide value to the question. Feel free to disagree though.

Comment: But then you do not nearly go far enough. There are so many other ways of the information you suggest getting out (vendors, job posting, etc.). That makes your approach more about tightly controlling *any* data disclosed publicly than inadvertant disclosure, and you then drift away from employees acting online, which takes you further from the question.

Comment: I don't understand the point you make. I pointed out related things one needs to be aware of. I never claimed that my answer was "complete" (whatever this may mean in this context), only that it was another thing to be aware of. What exactly are you getting at? That the answer is "not an answer" (and should therefore be deleted) or that the answer is incomplete?

Comment: That you are off on an unrelated tangent.

Comment: And I told you in my previous comment that I don't believe it's unrelated, giving you a reason why I feel that way.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with people in law enforcement and security arenas, and sometimes it is essential that you hide your employment from the public. When I was working on software products that would be used by the Northern Irish police, I was told specifically to not mention who I was working for, we even had to remove the company brands and name from the products in case it led to targetted attacks.

Soldiers and police are told not to wear their uniforms en route to work, to wear civilian dress and change at work, for unfortunately obvious reasons.

So, yes, I don't see why this woulnd't apply to any other sensitive company even if its nowhere near as serious as some of the examples I could give. You'll still need to be aware of the threats, and the threats may come your way regardless, but there's no reason to encourage them.

YMMV as to how effective you want to make it, or how seriously you take the threats to be, remembering that it would only a small part measure in tackling the problem.

Comment: I wonder how far this extends into private life. Are police officers told not to disclose to *anyone* that they are police officers?